# Check if user viewed object

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have a gallery with an `album` model.

I would like to save when a user looks at an album, to be able to filter out albums the user haven't seen.

How would you model this?

Create a `UserView` which is generated and stored on every first view it the first I can think of - but it feels like a lot of data to save.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, that's not a lot of data as you only have to store the `user_id` and `album_id`. Here's an example which lets you store the relevant data. It also ensures that the data you're trying to store is unique.

```
class AlbumView < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user
  belongs_to :album

  validates :user_id, presence: true, uniqueness: { scope: [:album_id] }
end

class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_one :album_view
end

# Won't fail if view already exists
AlbumView.create({
  user: current_user,
  album: album
})
```

Comment: has_one :album_view, why only one?

Answer (score 1):

I think you have the right idea. The `Album` model could `has_many :album_views`. 
Then your `User` model should have a `has_many :album_views`.

Then in your AlbumView model, set `belongs_to :album` and create a migration:

```
def change
  create_table :album_view do |t|
    t.integer :album_id
    t.integer :user_id

    t.timestamps null: false
  end
end
```

So when a user views an album, set the controller to call a custom FindOrCreate method that will find the album_view if it exists for that user and album, or else create it.

It may seem like a lot to create an object for each view, but data is cheap. :)